# How to make a chain of requests with axios in js

Tags: javascript, axios

I struggle with making 3 requests in such a way: I need an info from the first to send next two.

```
const order_id =  this.$route.params.order_id
          axios
          .get(`/api/v1/orders/${order_id}/`)
          .then(response => {
            this.order_main_info = response.data
          })
          .catch(err => {
            // console.log(err)
          })
```

In **this.order_main_info** *subject* and *worktype* are stored.

I need to send requests:

```
first_response = axios.get(`/api/v1/subjects/${this.order_main_info.subject}/`)
second_response = axios.get(`/api/v1/worktype/${this.order_main_info.worktype}/`)
```

and write results into **this.order_main_info** like this:

```
this.order_main_info["worktype_name"] = first_response.data.name
this.order_main_info["subject_name"] = second_response.data.name
```

I've tried a lot of times but still something wrong with syntax. Other questions on stackoverflow did not help me ((

I've tried both async/await and

```
.get ()
.then (
response => { axios.all() }
)
```

Comment: Why did you tag your question as `reactjs`? Please show the entire code you tried `axios.all` will of course not work, because you didn't pass any arguments.

Comment: axios.get(`/api/v1/orders/${order_id}/`)
 .then(response => {
     this.order_main_info = response.data;
     return axios.get(`/api/v1/subjects/${this.order_main_info.subject}/`);
 }).then(function (response) {
     this.order_main_info["worktype_name"] = response.data.name
     return axios.get(`/api/v1/worktype/${this.order_main_info.worktype}/`);
 }).then(function (response) {
     this.order_main_info["subject_name"] = response.data.name
 }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
 });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried nested axios calls?

Sample:

```js
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((response) => {
  const posts = response.data;
  axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${posts[0].id}`).then((response => {
    console.log(response.data)
  }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.0.0-alpha.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some troubles with axios spread construction.

the final working code looks like:

```
      const order_id =  this.$route.params.order_id
          axios
          .get(`/api/v1/orders/${order_id}/`)
          .then(response => {
            this.order_main_info = response.data
              const subject_id = response.data.subject
            const worktype_id = response.data.work_type
            axios.all([axios.get(`/api/v1/subjects/${subject_id}`),
                       axios.get(`/api/v1/worktypes/${worktype_id}`)
            ])
            .then (
            axios.spread((firstResponse, secondResponse) => {
            this.order_main_info["subject_name"] = firstResponse.data.name
            this.order_main_info["worktype_name"]= secondResponse.data.name
    }))
          })
```